How can I adjust the position of a Mixamo character so that when he stands up his feet stay on the floor?
I imported a "kneel" animation cycle from Mixamo, and the problem is that the hip bone remains in a static position, therefore when he kneels, from an objective viewpoint, his legs come up rather than his body going down with his feet staying on the floor. I've been fiddling with the graph editor and empty parenting but haven't quite figured out how to get it positioned so that the feet stay put and the body lowers during the animation. There don't seem to be any answers readily available for this specific kind of issue. I tried adapting the "correcting the slide issue" regarding a character's placement using the graph editor, but couldn't work out the right settings. Any help is appreciated. 

Okay, I was wondering if it could be done using the graph editor, but as I said I haven't worked it out that way. I can do keyframes to get the position of the hip bone to line up. Was just curious if there was a shortcut. Thanks.

This is a regular thing. You have to animate the root of the armature, usually near the pelvis, to get his body to move down as a whole. There’s no way to reverse it so that his feet stay still on their own.
Tip: Use the 3-D cursor as a reference point to mark where the front or back of a foot is when you do this.
